# Common integral question

Tags: integration

I was asked to find $$\int \sin^5x \, \mathrm dx$$ only in form of $\cos x$. I solved it using recursion, but I was getting something like $\cos^5x+ \cos^3x+\cos x$(obviously with some coefficients), but the options also had $\cos^4x+\cos^2x$ but I am not getting any, am I making some error, or I need to manipulate my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the recursions you used.

Comment: What answer did you get, and what is the answer you think you should be getting?

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\co}{\color{grey}{\rm constant}}\newcommand{\d}{{\rm d}}\int\sin^5x\d x\stackrel{t=\cos x}=-\int (1-t^2)^2\d t=\int(1+t^4-2t^2)\d t=-t-t^5/5+2t^3/3+\co\\=-\cos x-(1/5)\cos^5x+(2/3)\cos^3x+\co\\=\frac1{15} \cos(x) (3 \cos^4(x)-10 \cos^2(x)+15)+\co$$

Comment: Yeah, that is what I got. But where are the even powers of $\cos x$?

Comment: @mathgeek isn't the last form with even powers? check the answer by differentiating or upload it's image/mention exact answer for us

Comment: Finally when you multiply with $\cos x$, they all become odd.

Comment: @mathgeek :D did you read the second thing?

Comment: Sorry, what second thing? I want my final answer like in your second step.

Comment: @mathgeek what answer the asker provides you?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\sin^{2n+1}x\ dx=\int(1-\cos^2x)^n\sin x\ dx$$

Set $\cos x=u$

Comment: In this case too,you won't get even powers of cosx in the answer.

Comment: @mathgeek, Have you validated the answer, may be by differentiating? This helps you to avoid recursion

Comment: Yes, your answer as well as mine as well as that of WolframAlpha are same and correct, but I think we need some manipulation to get to the required form. Maybe our constant term might become diiferent or something else...